# What is the difference between these bits of code

Tags: python, division

I am just experimenting with some things in python, and one of my problems required a funny solution of changing a `/` to a `//`. What's the difference?

```py
def is_multiple(number=None, m=None): # m representing times table
    if not number or not m:
        return False
    if isinstance(m//number, float):
        return False
    return True
print(is_multiple(4, 12)) # returns True
```

```py
def is_multiple(number=None, m=None): # m representing times table
    if not number or not m:
        return False
    if isinstance(m/number, float):
        return False
    return True
print(is_multiple(4, 12)) # returns False
```

I would expect both to work the same, can someone explain the difference? Thanks :)

Comment: `m//number` is an int. `m/number` is a float.

Comment: Depending on if you are running Python 2 or Python 3, one of `/` is regular division, and one of `//` is integer (floor) division. From the Python repl try: `11//5` and see what the answer is.

Comment: You can also find information on the difference [here] (http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=674692&seqNum=4)